# ECS unable to assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch, aws-ecs

From the console, I am invoking a lambda which submits a batch job. The batch job fails, indicating that ECS is unable to assume the role that is provided to execute the job definition.

For the role, I've added the lambda and ECS services.

The error message:

> "ECS was unable to assume the role
>   'arn:aws:iam::749340585813:role/golfnow-invoke-write-progress' that
>   was provided for this task. Please verify that the role being passed
>   has the proper trust relationship and permissions and that your IAM
>   user has permissions to pass this role."

```
"TrainingJobRole": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "RoleName": "golfnow-invoke-write-progress",
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": [
              "lambda.amazonaws.com",
              "ecs.amazonaws.com"
            ]
          },
          "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Path": "/"
  }
}
```

The batch job:

```
    "TrainingJob": {
  "Type": "AWS::Batch::JobDefinition",
  "Properties": {
    "Type": "container",
    "JobDefinitionName": {
      "Fn::Sub": "c12e-golfnow-${Environment}-job"
    },
    "ContainerProperties": {
      "Image": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "{{ image omitted }}",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            },
            ".amazonaws.com/amazonlinux:latest"
          ]
        ]
      },
      "Vcpus": 2,
      "Memory": 2000,
      "Command": [
        "while", "True", ";", "do", "echo", "'hello';", "done"
      ],
      "JobRoleArn": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "TrainingJobRole",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    },
    "RetryStrategy": {
      "Attempts": 1
    }
  }
},
"JobQueue": {
  "Type": "AWS::Batch::JobQueue",
  "Properties": {
    "Priority": 1,
    "ComputeEnvironmentOrder": [
      {
        "Order": 1,
        "ComputeEnvironment": {
          "Ref": "ComputeEnvironment"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is the issue with the way it's being invoked? My user has admin privileges, so I don't think this is an issue with my user having insufficient permissions.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You have to add the principal "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com" to the trust policy for the role that's submitting a Batch job (not "ecs.amazonaws.com").

Revised role:

```
"TrainingJobRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": "golfnow-invoke-write-progress",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "lambda.amazonaws.com",
                  "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path": "/"
      }
    },
```

Comment: All documentations (including official AWS docs) I've found was referring to add ecs.amazonaws.com to the trust policy but not ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com. This answer helped me to fix the issue with the missing principal.

Comment: @balas, I agree. Once I looked at _Trust Relationships_ of a working ECS role in the console I noticed that that the entity listed is `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com` (unfortunately I only noticed it after I found this question)

Comment: Note that ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com seems to be the required service regardless of whether you're working with batch jobs etc or not.

Comment: In my case, the problem was happening because the path was configured with other value than "Path": "/"

Comment: You can actually find the official documentation for this here : https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-ecs-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/task_execution_IAM_role.md

Answer (score 2):

And for those who are writing CDK script in Java, while defining the `TaskDefinition` you don't have to explicitly provide any `taskRole` and `executionRole`. CDK will create appropriate Role for you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a trust policy to ECS to call the Batch service.

```
   "Principal": {
      "Service":  [
            "batch.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by adding role name in the CDK script.

```
 const ecsFargateServiceRole = new iam.Role(this, 'execution-role', {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com'),
  roleName: "execution-role"
});
ecsFargateServiceRole.addToPolicy(executionRolePolicy);
```

Comment: As mentioned by @horizon7, you shouldn't need to specify an IAM role unless you need to add additional policies to it.

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer he mentioned if using JAVA. The above code is of JavaScript.

Comment: SDKs are pretty much the same across languages. You don't need to specify this bit `roleName: "execution-role"`

Answer (score 0):

i got a similar issue, but it's python. and the solution here seems not working.
pls check and help, [aws lambda function can't update ecs service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76361527/aws-lambda-function-cant-update-ecs-service)