# aws lambda function can't update ecs service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

**When** trying to update_service of a ecs service using python boto3, i got the error is like this:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the UpdateService operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/infra-conductors/infra-conductors is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/ecs/ecsTaskExecutionRole-test with an explicit deny in a service control policy

but i've already added permissions and trust policy to this lambda:

```
{
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/ecs/ecsTaskExecutionRole-test"
        ],
        "Sid": "test"
    },
```

and,

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": [
                "lambda.amazonaws.com",
                "ecs.amazonaws.com",
                "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]
```

}

**BTW**, i attached other permissions to this lambda, and it can reboot a ecs service or change the `desiredCount`, but when i trying to change the taskdef, i got this error.

Answer (score 3):

The error says that it was denied `with an explicit deny`. This means, that somewhere, there is a policy that **explicitly** denies what you are trying to do. Since `deny` statement always takes [precedence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html) over any `allow`, first you have to find the policy with the `deny` and remove the `deny`.

Comment: The `in a service control policy` part of the error message indicates that this explicit deny is most likely in a Service Control Policy (SCP) applied to the whole account so it may be difficult to find unless you have access to the Organization Management account. You should probably talk to your AWS Admin/Security People.

Comment: yeah, i found the explicit deny in our SCP. thx.
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
     {
      "Sid": "ExplicitIAMPassRole",
      "Action": [
        "iam:PassRole"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnNotLike": {

Comment: @reachlin Is it still unclear why you get access denied?

Comment: @Marcin, thanks. i found the SCP disabled the PassRole. Now my question is it possible to update service without change the SCP. because it is set globally by the company.

Comment: @reachlin Sadly, its not possible. That's the entire point of explicit denies.